# Attaching a HDMI screen to my Macbook interferes with Network access

Tags: network, wifi, usb, hdmi

I have a Macbook Pro and an USB-C Adapter where I can attach a HDMI screen.

Without a screen attached:

- on the iPad remote I press the *Play* button turns green
- Once I press the Stop button the *Play* button instantly goes back to white and the Stop button changes into a *Skip Back* button

Now I attach a HDMI screen and the Remote now is either responds sluggishly or can't even connect to Logic Pro.

The problem is reproducible so in order for the Remote to work I need to unplug the HDMI monitor.

#### Update

I am using a Macbook Pro TocuhBar 13". The USB-C Adapter I'm using is from [Satechi](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1520/4366/products/SATECHI_typeC_MacbookPRO_NEWexpansion_silver_1.jpg?v=1533846181). However

I realised that attaching the monitor via HDMI it will generally affect my network connectivity. I had troubles with both, connecting to my Wifi and also browsing the web.

When the screen is attached it takes approx 12 seconds to load **google.com**.

[image]
As soon as a the screen is removed it takes less than half a second.

[image]

Comment: Which MacBook Pro (i.e. 2015? 13" or 15").  Are you using a built in HDMI port or a USB to HDMI adapter?  If so, which brand/model?

Comment: @Allan I did update my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

USB-C to HDMI adapters are known to heavily interfere with WiFi adapters in MacBooks, when they are located close to each other.  So, what you can do:

1. Use DisplayPort cable and USB-C to DisplayPort adapter instead of HDMI (if your display has a DisplayPort socket)
2. Plug you USB-C to HDMI adapter into a USB-C socket at the other side of your MacBook (if your MacBook has such a socket on the other side)
3. Wrap your USB-C to HDMI adapter with tin foil, and then with isolation tape (in case there is a cable segment between the adapter and the USB-C plug)

I personally used the third option and if works fine for me.

Comment: DisplayPort would be best option if that is available as that means less complexity in the signal path for trouble of many kinds, beyond just WiFi interference.  Trying VGA is also an option, I recall DisplayPort to VGA adapters being inexpensive and many new displays having VGA still.  Rolls of aluminum tape to block radio noise should not be too difficult to find at most hardware stores, they’d likely be found among ductwork and possibly among siding.

Comment: Quick note that VGA is analog and may cause quality loss!

Comment: Indeed, loss of quality with VGA is possible but the resolution that a good DP-to-VGA adapter offers can exceed that of many DP-to-HDMI adapters.  If the display has VGA and not DP then that limits options.  Adapters are likely much cheaper than a new display, and if buying a new display to resolve this issue then get a display with USB-C to avoid the need for any adapter.  VGA will have some inherent noise introduced in the conversion but not likely noticeable.  The display will scale the VGA signal to fit so just find a setting that gives best results.